# Selenium FindElements() times out. Get around unpredictable loading icons

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I've searched quite a bit on this topic on the stack and other places.
When I run driver.FindElements(By.myselector) my browser waits 60 seconds to time out. Instead of returning an empty list as described by the documentation
( https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/ ). It seems to be a great solution to work around an element possibly being in the DOM.

I need to check for the possible existence of loading icons/gifs. When the icons are present I need to wait until they are gone. When the icons are not there I need the method to fail to find MUCH faster than 60 seconds so I can let the script continue to test. The loading icon's appearance is not always predictable.

**Is there a way to**

1. Make an individual operation fail quickly?
2. Get FindElements() to return an empty list instead of failing after 60 seconds?
3. Get around unpredictable DOM blocking loading icons another way?

***Examples of code I have tried:***

Find if any elements are returned. Originally had a loop to keep checking if empty. If not Thread.Sleep() then reassign and check for existence again. Waits 60 seconds to fail.

```
        public static IWebElement FindElementIfExists(ChromeDriver _driver, By by)
        {
                ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = _driver.FindElements(by);
                return (elements.Count >= 1) ? elements[0] : null;
        }
```

This code works when the loading icon shows up, but Selenium waits 60 seconds and fails on

> *OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL timeout after 60 seconds* when the icon is
> not in the DOM.

```
public static bool isElementDisplayed(ChromeDriver _driver, By aSelector)
        {
            try
            {
               // WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(aSelector));
                return _driver.FindElement(aSelector).Displayed;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is NoSuchElementException || ex is StaleElementReferenceException || ex is TimeoutException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }

            public static void WaitForElementToBeGone(ChromeDriver _driver, By aSelector, int timeout)
            {
                if (isElementDisplayed(_driver, aSelector))
                {
                new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(_driver.FindElement(aSelector)));
                                                             
                }
            }
```

Thanks again

Comment: Why wait for it if it might not exist? Why not check for the existence of the element first, and if it exists, then wait for it to disappear? - (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/32449/force-selenium-to-wait-for-spinner-to-disappear-before-resuming)

Comment: My guess is that you have an implicit wait set to 60s in your code and that's why it's taking 60s to timeout. According to the Selenium creator, using implicit waits is a bad practice. According to the docs, mixing implicit and explicit (WebDriverWait) waits should not be done either. Remove all implicit wait calls, use WebDriverWait where waits are needed, and then do what Ryan suggested above.

Comment: I can't check the existence of an element because FindElements() never returns an empty list. It finds a element or breaks the code. I'll check for implicit waits but I don't believe they are there.

Comment: No Implicit waits in the code.

Comment: @JeffC I set implicit wait to 0 milliseconds so there would be no implicit wait and it worked fine! Thanks for suggestion on Implicit wait. I guess there was a default implicit wait time.